# FileNotFoundException in File constructor

Tags: unit-testing, grails, spock

I'm working on a grails application and having trouble unit testing a statement that has this block of code

```
DateTime getExifTimestamp(UploadedFile uploadedFile) {
    // Get the metadata directory with the timestamp
    ExifSubIFDDirectory directory = ImageMetadataReader
            .readMetadata(new File(uploadedFile.currentPath))
            .getDirectory(ExifSubIFDDirectory.class)

    def retVal = new LocalDateTime(directory.getDate(ExifSubIFDDirectory.TAG_DATETIME_ORIGINAL)).toDateTime()
    log.trace("Image time: $retVal")
    // TODO: Pull this sort of logging into an annotation or something else

    retVal
}
```

whenever I call this method, the ExifSubIFDDirectory line always chokes and gives the following error message

```
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: currentPath (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:146)
    at com.drew.imaging.ImageMetadataReader.readMetadata(ImageMetadataReader.java:86)
    at com.witsmd.pronghorn.ConvertToDicomService.$tt__getExifTimestamp(ConvertToDicomService.groovy:164)
    at com.witsmd.pronghorn.ConvertToDicomServiceSpec.(ConvertToDicomServiceSpec.groovy:149)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me this looks like the file name is "currentPath", which probably is not what you want, is it?